# What does two lambda function together means

Tags: haskell, lambda

This is an example from my lecture note

```
ap_List :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
-- ap_List [] as = []
-- ap_List (f:fs) as = map f as ++ ap_List fs as
ap_List fs as = map2_List (\f -> \a -> f a) fs as 
-- E.g., ap_List [f,g] [1,2,3] = [f 1, f 2, f 3, g 1, g 2, g 3]
--                             = map f [1,2,3] ++ (map g [1,2,3] ++ [])
```

For the line

```
ap_List fs as = map2_List (\f -> \a -> f a) fs as
```

I don't understand what `(\f -> \a -> f a)` represents. Usually, a lambda function would be followed by some input element. But here it is followed by another lambda function. Could anyone explain what it means? Thank you!

Comment: `\f -> \a -> f a` is the long-hand way of writing `\f a -> f a`.

Comment: It's a function that takes an argument `f` and returns another function, which takes an argument `a` and returns `f` applied to `a`. In this case, such a function is already provided: it's `($)`. A shorter definition would have been `ap_List = map2_List ($)`.

Comment: And `($)` is just `id`, so `ap_List = map2_List id` works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **curried** function. It has `f` as argument and returns a function that has `a` as argument and returns `f a`. This effectively simulates a function with two arguments.

Note that that particular lambda function is same as the operator `$`.